# How to get specific city with all related schools in @Query annotation

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

I have two domain class City and School with OneToMany.

```
@Entity
public class City {
 ...
 @OneToMany(mappedBy="city")
 private Set<School> schools = new HashSet<>();
 ...
}
@Entity
public class School {
 ...
 @ManyToOne
 private City city;
 ...
}
```

The corresponding repository are:

```
@Repository
public interface CityRepository extends JpaRepository<City, Long>{
}
@Repository
public interface SchoolRepository extends JpaRepository<School, Long> {
}
```

In the CityController's method:

```
@GetMapping(....)
public ResponseEntity<City> getSchool(@PathVariable Long id) {
 City city = cityRepository.findOne(id);
 return ResponseUtil.wrapOrNotFound(Optional.ofNullable(city));
}
```

When I debug to check schools member of the city object, there is an exception:
Unable to evaluate the expression Method threw 'org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException' exception.

Don't know why, I just want to get the city with all schools in that city (but don't want to add some annotation to domain class, I prefer to implement it in @Repository, better using @Query). Appreciated for any help.

Comment: I tried:@Query("select city from City city join fetch city.schools where city.id = ?1") and can get schools information, however, inside each school, attached the city information, there existed cross link endlessly.

Answer (score 2):

In Hibernate, all relationships have FetchType.LAZY by default. You need to set it to eager to get the city.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private City city;
```

Comment: I don't want to apply fetch = FetchType.EAGER to the city member, I prefer custom method in repository, is that possible?

Comment: I don't think that can be done while using Spring repository

Comment: ok, thanks, I think it is a normal requirement, should be a JPQL solution which can do that.